# How to mix normal and slice arguments in python

Tags: python, slice, numpy-ndarray

I have a class and I would like to create an instance from an array, plus a slice. I would like the syntax to use the colon syntax as used by e.g. lists and numpy arrays. The following example is a MNWE (minimal non-working example):

```
import numpy as np

class A():

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data.__getitem__(index)

    @classmethod
    def fromArray(cls, array, index):
        return cls(array.__getitem__(index))

x = np.empty((4, 2, 2)) 
a = A(x)
print(a[:, 0, 0]) 

# Create from array, using slices:
my_slices = (slice(0, -1, 1), slice(0, 1, None), slice(0, 1, None))
b = A.fromArray(x, my_slices)
print(b.data)

# Create from array, using slice colon syntax (fails):
c = A.fromArray(x, :, 0, 0)
print(c.data)
```

I would like the results to be the same, apart from flat dimensions.

Comment: What does MNWE mean?

Comment: @PeterWood "Minimal Non Working Example" ?

Comment: @PeterWood Sorry, corrected in the text.

Comment: The Python language grammar just doesn't work like that. You can't use slice syntax in function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what you are trying to do is possible.

What about making a factory class ?

```
class AFactory:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return A.fromArray(self.x, index)

c = AFactory(x)[:, 0, 0]
print(c.data)
```

Or if you prefer setting the slice before the array:

```
class AFactory:
    def __getitem__(cls, index):
        return lambda x: A.fromArray(x, index)

c = AFactory()[:, 0, 0](x)
print(c.data)
```